# MVC 3 App spawning multiple threads for a particular user

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am working on an mvc3 application with EF 4.  The build runs fine for all developers, except for one user.  When that user runs the app, they get a redirect loop error in chrome, and when inspecting the code in the debugger logged in as this user, I can see multiple threads spawning for no apparent reason.  There is no explicit thread starting or management in the application, and this issue persists regardless of the default start page specified for debugging.

I'd be happy to post code, but am at a bit of a loss on where to begin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont see how new threads would cause this problem. Have you tried placing breakpoints at all calls to Response.Redirect? Have you checked the http headers returned by your application?

Answer (score 0):

So I started from the entry point and went through the code from start to finish.  It ended up being a redirect in a filter attribute that should have been deprecated, but was still being called.  It was poorly constructed, and failure states for the OnActionExecuting resulted in a redirect to '/', and you can see the result.

Thanks for giving my head a virtual shake and getting me back to basics.  The multiple threads were a symptom, not a root cause.